# Flutter get Image.Asset from List

Tags: flutter, image, dart

So I want to get images from a list, which contains the filename of the image provided for the project as demonstrated like this.

[image]

So this is our list:

```
const product = [
  {
    "assets": "pizza.png",
    "name": "Mathematics Tasks",
    "info": "Quiz on Module 3",
    "score": 20,
  },
  {
    "assets": "burger.png",
    "name": "Science Tasks",
    "info": "Quiz on Module 8",
    "score": 50,
  },
  {
    "assets": "fries.png",
    "name": "Technology Tasks",
    "info": "Activity on Module 2",
    "score": 5,
  },
  {
    "assets": "hotdog.png",
    "name": "Arts Tasks",
    "info": "Quiz on Module 3",
    "score": 20,
  },
];
```

And how we are getting each one goes by this code:

```
Image.asset("assets/${product['assets']}")
```

As depicted in the image above, it doesn't display it, but we are certain that code works. We even declared its location in our pubspec.yaml file, directing to the images at the assets folder. I know we can insert the names of the files respectively, but we decided it would be easier and organized if we kept it in a list to avoid overcomplicating matters. Was  there something wrong with how it was done or are the variables the issue?

And to those asking for the pubspec.yaml file, here it is:

```
name: test_project
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

And no, I do not use other folders for this case, but if I must, the I would add the "assets/folder". Not adding what packages are used since this doesn't exactly use packages...

Comment: is `product` getting from api? Can you include how you've structured the `yaml`?

Comment: Please provide pubspec.yaml file also. So that we understand how you add images.

Answer (score 0):

try this

on your project create a folder named **assets** inside the asset folder create another one named **png** where all you're images.

so the arrangement to that will be

```
assets
   |__ png
```

now go to your **pubspec.yaml**  add the path to your assets

```
assets:
    - assets/png/
```

now you're done adding them create a constant for this and named it image.dart in depend on you whats the name. Now inside the image.dart

```
const String? pizza = "assets/png/pizza.png";
const String? burger = "assets/png/burger.png";
```

something like this.

now on your list edit those to like this and call the images name.

```
const product = [
  {
    "assets": pizza!,
    "name": "Mathematics Tasks",
    "info": "Quiz on Module 3",
    "score": 20,
  },
  {
    "assets": burger!,
    "name": "Science Tasks",
    "info": "Quiz on Module 8",
    "score": 50,
  }
];
```

now lastly when you go calling them it still the same calling at like you did.

```
Image.asset(product[index]['assets'])
```

or

```
Image.asset(product['assets'])
```

i hope it helps i usually do mine like this.

Comment: Well, this does work, but having stings there and calling individual indexes from the list can get the entire list at one without needing multiple Strings. Although I think I can work with this for the time being.